# Antiforgery cookie in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I've been trying to understand exactly how the antiforgery works. What confuses me are the cookies which are created. To my understanding, you include the antiforgery token in your form and then you validate for that token when a request is made. This way if a third party websites posts to your website, it will be denied.

Now, I'm reading here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-2.1 that the antiforgery token gets stored in a cookie, maybe I'm reading this wrong? But why? Isn't the whole point of this not to make this value accessible outside of your website? If I look at my cookies, I can see 3 cookies created with antiforgery in their name.

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options => 
{
    options.CookieDomain = "contoso.com";
    options.CookieName = "X-CSRF-TOKEN-COOKIENAME";
    options.CookiePath = "Path";
    options.FormFieldName = "AntiforgeryFieldname";
    options.HeaderName = "X-CSRF-TOKEN-HEADERNAME";
    options.RequireSsl = false;
    options.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = false;
});
```

I did a little test, I created a post form which ended up including anti forgery token and then I tried submitting it and it worked. Then I created another form without the token and then it failed. So to me it seems it only looks for the token passed in the form, then what is the cookie for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anti-forgery is a two-part process. When the page is generated, the token is included as part of the form, so that it will be posted along with the rest of your data. The cookie is set, for the client side of things. When the post is made, the client sends the request with the post data (including the token) *and* it sends the cookie back to the server, which also includes the token. Server-side, the posted token is matched up with the cookie token, and rejected if the two don't match.

This may seem weird since the client is posting both, but the cookie part ensures that the same client that got the page is also the same client sending it back. The goal isn't so much to protect the anti-forgery token, but rather to ensure that the page on your site is the one that's submitted, rather than some scammer's recreated version of your page. Since a third-party would be incapable of setting a cookie for your domain, there's no way they can fake this portion of the check, even if they were able to retrieve a valid token from your page by requesting it and parsing out the token.

Comment: So basically you are saying that the value in the cookie is compared to the value in the html? If so, then as a hacker, why don't I just copy the cookie value into my html? What is preventing me from getting the cookie value from the browser?

Comment: Cookies are domain-bound. Only the server that set them can read/write them. In other words, a malicious server cannot set a cookie with the token that will be seen by the real server.

Comment: If this is in fact how it works, then I'm confused as to how the [ajax approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks#anti-csrf-and-ajax) is secure. If all the validation does is check that the two match, could a forger not simply set the csrf header to something like `a:a`?

Comment: It works because, again, the token itself doesn't need to be secure. What makes it work is that the server generates the token, and the on-page AJAX must get it from the page, whether set as a JS var or hidden input. A third-party can't match the two up. Now, if you're returning tokens from an API endpoint or something, then you're right: that won't work, but that's not how it's supposed to be done.

Comment: In .net 5 Is the cookie value also encrypted? The token value inside the form field and the Antiforgey cookie value are different . I am guessing the cookie value is the encrypted value of the token.

Answer (score 0):

From the asp.net core website [AntiforgeryOptions.Cookie Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.antiforgery.antiforgeryoptions.cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Antiforgery_AntiforgeryOptions_Cookie). The cookie part of the CSRF is only necessary when using cookie based authentication.

> The cookie used by the antiforgery system is part of a security system that is necessary when using cookie-based authentication.